# SELECT multiple data from MySQL node.js with promises

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, promise

The concept of promises is very new for me (so far, I was working with async.each and async.waterfall)
I want to use promises but i'm stuck right now.

I want to get "tags" from my db. 
I have two tables for this : One called 'tags' with every tag in it (with an ID) and another one 'user_tags' with every username saved and the ID of the tag that the user (username) created and saved into 'tags'.

I can put information in my DB but now I want to pull this out and log it out (I will display it later)

So far this is my idea :

```
var getUserprofile = function getUserprofile(username, callback){
  pool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
    var dataUser = [];

    // Error check
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }

    connection.query('SELECT * FROM users_tags FULL JOIN tags ON (tags.id = users_tags.t_id) WHERE users_tags.user_id=666;', username , function (err, rows, fields) {
      if (err) {
        connection.release();
        cb(err);
      } else if (rows.length < 1) {
        connection.release();
        cb("We don't have any informations about this user yet");

      } else {
        console.log("we pull the information right now");
        connection.release();
        callback(null, rows[0]);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Is this a good idea ? What should I do if I want to use promises for this kind of function ?
Thanks in advance for any help !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use [Bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api-reference.html). You can "promisify" existing APIs with [Promise.promisify](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisify.html) or [Promise.promisifyAll](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisifyall.html).

I would do something like

```
var Promise = require('bluebird'),
     ... //other deps;

var pool = Promise.promisifyAll(pool);
function getUserprofile(username){
    var connection = null;
    return pool.getConnectionAsync()
        .then(function (conn) {
             connection = Promise.promisifyAll(conn);
             return connection.queryAsync('...');
        })
        .then(function (results) {
             if (results.length < 1) {
                 return "We don't have any informations about this user yet";
             } else {
                 console.log("we pull the information right now");
                 return results[0];
             }
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
             console.log(err);
             throw err;
        })
        .finally(function () {
             if (connection) {
                 connection.release();
             }
        });
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, had no idea about bluebird. I'm checking it right now. But there is something weird for me in your answer, your connection to the db doesn't look like mine at all. I don't really get it. It is a must ? Why mine is not good then ?
Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I simply used the promisified version (`getConnectionAsync`) of the API to create a connection. What does trouble you?

Comment: I've been using this     "pool.getConnection(function (err, connection)" method on all my project, if I start using the    (getConnectionAsync) method, it means that I have to change all my request so far right ? 
    I already have a var pool declared.

Comment: Well, it's up to you. For example, you could use the promise version for your connection only (`queryAsync`), but wouldnt be better to use promises in both cases (pool AND connection)? ;)

Comment: Well i've done it without promises. I had to use async.each to loop on my [] and it works. I'm keeping your example because I need it somewhere else anyway. I want to use them for my next function which is getUserPictures.
So thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Happy to be of help. Could you please accept the answer? Thanks